# Build PHP array with string and result 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a smart problem in PHP, I build an array with a string, and at the same time I cut some images.
`buildProject.php` is include in `index.php` (session_start(); for _session is on the top of it).

**buildProject.php**

```
<?php
  $list_projet = array(
    0 => 'img0_pres',
    1 => 'img1_pres',
    2 => 'img2_pres',
  );
  $height_decoup = 500;
  $projet = array();

  foreach ($list_projet as $key => $value) {
    $name_source = $value;
    $img_source_file = 'images/projet/'.$name_source.'.jpg';
    $img_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_source_file);

    $width = imagesx($img_source);
    $height = imagesy($img_source);
    $ratio = ceil($height/$height_decoup);
    $img_dest_height = $height_decoup;

    $nb_img_decoup = 1;
    $img_source_y = 0;

    while ($nb_img_decoup <= $ratio) {
      if ($nb_img_decoup == $ratio) {
        $img_dest_height = $height - $height_decoup*($ratio-1);
      }
      $img_dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$img_dest_height);
      imagecopy($img_dest, $img_source, 0, 0, 0, $img_source_y, $width, $img_dest_height);
      $img_dest_file = 'images/projet/'.$name_source.'_'.$nb_img_decoup.'.jpg';
      imagejpeg($img_dest, $img_dest_file);

      $projet[$key][$nb_img_decoup] = $img_dest_file; // I SUPPOSE AN ERROR HERE
      $img_source_y += $height_decoup;
      $nb_img_decoup++;
    }
    imagedestroy($img_source);
    imagedestroy($img_dest);
  }
  echo $img_dest_file[0]; // give me an 'i' and suppose give me an error
  echo $projet[0][1][0]; // idem...

  $_SESSION['txt'] = $projet;
?>
```

After build it, I send it to `getProjet.php` to find it on `main.js` with `getJSON`.
My Probleme is `$img_dest_file` transform alone in array and i need a string!

I thinks the problem is on `buildProject.php` but I put the other files maybe there are an other error can do that.

**getProject.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$projet = $_SESSION['txt'];

if(isset($_GET['list']) && $_GET['list']>=0){
    echo json_encode($projet[$_GET['list']]);
} ?>
```

**main.js**

```
$.getJSON('php/getProject.php?list=' + index, function(data) {
    length = data.length;
    console.log(data+' //// '+length); // [object object] //// undefined
    console.log(data[1].length); // 29 (total of caracteres...)
    console.log(data[1]); // images/projet/img0_pres_1.jpg (I need that)
    console.log(data[1][0]); // i (But not that, here I want an error)
}
```

So in `main.js` `data=([object object])` and I need `data=([object])`.
I think it's because when i run `buildProject.php` `$img_dest_file` transform alone in array and it's normaly just a string not an array.

If someone has an idea why `$img_dest_file` transform alone in array?

The main think i need is data.lengh, and it's actualy undefined.

Thanks for reading. If you have question I can specify more.

Comment: How you call **buildProject.php**  in your code??

Comment: It's include in index.php

Comment: exe : img1_pres.jpg is cut in differents part with `buildProjet.php` : img1_pres_0.jpg, img1_pres_1.jpg, img1_pres_2.jpg, img1_pres_3.jpg. In `main.js' I need data.lengh = 4. And it actualy give me : undefine. Because, data = ([object, object]), and i suppose receive data = ([object]).

Comment: Here $projet[$key][$nb_img_decoup] you are building a 2 dimensional array. Besides you could use console.dir(data) instead.

Comment: thanks for console.dir ;) Yes I build a 2 dimensional array but i give me a 3 dimensional array. But when i read it on main.js I juste call projet[0] for exemple, look at getProject.php I juse call the 1st dimension i need and after i navigate on directly the 2nd dimension, I don't call all project.

Answer (score 0):

I think, **while** loop is iterating until "nb_img_decoup" is not getting less than or equal to "ratio". If that loops iterate more than once for same "key" then it will create multiple records/indices for same "key".

That is why when $projet[$_GET['list']] is being searched it is returning multiple records and hence [object object].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just test now with on passage on the while, and i have the same result. I realy thinks the problem is on the base, when I build the array, I build a 2 dimensional array and I have a 3 demensional array in result.

Comment: But if you are true how you conseil me to build the array?

Comment: $projet[$key][$nb_img_decoup] = $img_dest_file; should be after (outside) the while loop